# issue with Google translation API

Tags: java, google-translate, google-translation-api

I need an example to convert Spanish language to English  language using Google Translation API. I tried with the following code. It gives some exception. can someone help me on the same.

Code :

```
import  com.google.api.translate.*;
public class GoogleTranslator {

    /**
     * @param args

    */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args) {// TODO code application logic here


            try {
                Translate.setHttpReferrer("sp-en");
                String translatedText = Translate.translate("Hola mundo", Language.SPANISH, Language.ENGLISH);
                System.out.println(translatedText);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace(); }

    }
}
```

**Error :**

```
java.lang.Exception: [google-api-translate-java] Error retrieving translation.
    at com.google.api.GoogleAPI.retrieveJSON(GoogleAPI.java:136)
    at com.google.api.translate.Translate.execute(Translate.java:69)
    at com.google.api.translate.Translate.translate(Translate.java:192)
    at GoogleTranslator.main(GoogleTranslator.java:15)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ajax.googleapis.com
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.api.GoogleAPI.retrieveJSON(GoogleAPI.java:115)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/issues/detail?id=52

Comment: Try to ping the server. I can see it from here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out why you don't reach this host: ajax.googleapis.com

The Exception says:

```
 java.net.UnknownHostException: ajax.googleapis.com
```

The javadoc says UnknownHostException is thrown to indicate that the IP address of a host could not be determined.

You should your DNS.

> nslookup ajax.googleapis.com

Answer (score 0):

Set your DNS to google one

if on linux machine

`sudo gedit /etc/resolv.conf`

add

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

or if on windows goto network setting and set DNS for active connection

Answer (score 0):

you don't have an api key, for example GoogleAPI.setKey(); you need something like this to continue i guess